# When does Asio's timer throws while canceling?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, timer, asio

Boost Asio's `steady_timer::cancel()` may throw a `boost::system::system_error`.

Under what circumstances can this happen?

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/cancel/overload1.html

---

The current Networking TS has a `basic_waitable_timer` with a not `noexcept` `.cancel()` function. Has the `noexcept` been forgotten here or can the function also throw exceptions?

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4734.pdf `[timer.waitable.ops]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under what circumstances can this happen?

I can't think of any. Note that the overload taking an error_code reference has been deprecated: [*(Deprecated: Use non-error_code overload.)*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/cancel.html)

This tells me the error interface was excess.